# d3 selection .attr, .property, etc setter methods' behaviour when value is undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

What is the expected behaviour when I call `d3.select("input[type=checkbox]").property("checked", undefined)`?

Should it be treated as falsy and thus the `checked` property set to `false`/removed, or should it be treated as no value and thus like calling `.property("checked")`, the getter?

Comment: I just tried it in the console and the returned value is your `input[type=checkbox]`

Comment: So that means it's treated as a setter, however is the checked property set to `false` for you?

Comment: apparently it is, and without changing the `property` in the DOM

Comment: @fra9001, if I understand you correctly, the "property in the DOM" is not a property: it's an attribute. The attribute for this element is the initial value of the property.

Answer (score 1):

The property method

```
d3_selectionPrototype.property = function (name, value) {
    if (arguments.length < 2) {
        if (typeof name === "string") return this.node()[name];
        for (value in name) this.each(d3_selection_property(value, name[value]));
        return this;
    }
    return this.each(d3_selection_property(name, value)); 
};
```

When you pass in the value `undefined`, since you've passed in 2 arguments, it calls d3_selection_property (for each entry in the selection) which is

```
function d3_selection_property(name, value) {
    function propertyNull() {
        delete this[name];
    }
    function propertyConstant() {
        this[name] = value;
    }
    function propertyFunction() {
        var x = value.apply(this, arguments);
        if (x == null) delete this[name]; else this[name] = x;
    }
    return value == null ? propertyNull : typeof value === "function" ? propertyFunction : propertyConstant; }
```

The non-strict comparison (last line) `value == null` evaluates to true when value === undefined and so `propertyNull` is called doing this

```
delete this[name];
```

However, since the `checked` property is not actually on the `this` object (it's actually one level up the prototype chain of the DOM element), this actually does nothing.

---

So to sum up, **it returns the selection (as all chainable d3 methods do), but it doesn't modify the actual checked value.**

---

As per the documentation - https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections

> If value is specified, sets the property with the specified name to
>   the specified value on all selected elements.

but as per the current code, that won't happen if the specified value is `undefined`

Comment: Hm, does this mean `undefined` is treated the same as `null`? As far as I know, `null` is supposed to remove the property from the actual DOM node.